# Tips and tricks for performance tuning of web application

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I need to have different options to optimize performance and speed up web application.

Basically I need for asp.net web applications. 
What do you follow while building an web application or website considering performance of the website or web application ?

Please help with suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This need not be community wiki.

Comment: Exactly. But I thought this is a kind of subjective or descriptive qst.

Comment: You can edit the question and make it non-CW.

Comment: How to do it? I can't find any option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read

[Best Practices For Speeding Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

1. Minimize HTTP Requests
2. Use a Content Delivery Network
3. Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header
4. Gzip Components
5. Put Stylesheets at the Top
6. Put Scripts at the Bottom
7. Avoid CSS Expressions
8. Make JavaScript and CSS External
9. Reduce DNS Lookups
10. Minify JavaScript and CSS
11. Avoid Redirects
12. Remove Duplicate Scripts
13. Configure ETags
14. Make Ajax Cacheable
15. Flush the Buffer Early
16. Use GET for AJAX Requests
17. Post-load Components
18. Preload Components
19. Reduce the Number of DOM Elements
20. Split Components Across Domains
21. Minimize the Number of iframes
22. No 404s
23. Reduce Cookie Size
24. Use Cookie-free Domains for Components
25. Minimize DOM Access
26. Develop Smart Event Handlers
27. Choose  over @import
28. Avoid Filters
29. Optimize Images
30. Optimize CSS Sprites
31. Don't Scale Images in HTML
32. Make favicon.ico Small and Cacheable
33. Keep Components under 25K
34. Pack Components into a Multipart Document

You can use **[YSlow for Firebug](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)** to measure the performance of your page.

Answer (score 1):

Check asp.NET optimization

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44e5wy6k(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

10 tips for speeding up ASP.NET Web applications:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx

I usually trawl the Web for conference slide decks, etc :-)

Answer (score 1):

One tip: make sure you **know** where the bottlenecks are before you start optimising.

Use profiling tools and the tips mentioned in the links to find where your app is probably being slowed down.  Many devs get caught in premature optimisation or optimising the wrong bits of code and just waste their time.

Answer (score 1):

If your web application makes significant use of a database you should also look at optimising that...database access code can be a greater cause of slow performance than download times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great a **[reference](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx)**.

[**http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Tuning .NET Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx) also. It has some valuable suggestions when it come to performance issue.